# Excel macro to convert CSV to XSLM with no date formatting

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I hope you can help. I've got an Excel VBA macro that to automate the saving of a CSV as a XLSM file. However, when it does so, it changes the date formatting that is in the CSV to the default local UK settings. I need it to not do that and keep the original date format.

The orginal date format is mm/dd/yyyy in the CSV file and I need this to be maintained in the XLSM format. Currently the macro allows Excel to change the format to dd/mm/yyyy (local UK setting).

By way of example in the CSV:

```
05/24/2017,2,3,email@email.com
```

Becomes the following, in the saved XLSM file:

```
24/05/2017  2   3   email@email.com
```

This is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim strFile As String, strDir As String

    strDir = "C:\Processing\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.csv")

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
    With wb
        .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsm"), 52  'UPDATE:
        .Close True
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing


    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

The wildcards are being used in the code as the name of the file is changeable.

Hope you can help.

Comment: The Informations that you provide are not enough. What is the format you want and how is it changed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Instead of opening the csv directly, use the `Data >> From text` method, where you can specify the format of specific columns.

Comment: Apologies for not being more explicit. I have updated the query above. I'm don't think the Data >> From Text would help here as the process has to be run by the macro as part of an automated process. We're not able to manually open the file and import it.